# Access bring me random records from a selected column

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want access give me the the first value from the selected table and column.
But access are given to me random value from the selected table and column.

**Question**

Have  someway to access give to me like this example:

My table is "tblExample" and have 2 columns the header of each is [Column1] and [Column2] inside each header contains this values

```
                +---------+----------+
                | Column1 | Column2  |
                +---------+----------+
                | 5       | mark     |
                | 3       | stewie   |
                | 2       | stack    |
                | 16      | overflow |
                +---------+----------+
```

I want read the first value in loop of the [Column1] from the table "tblExample" and bring to me in sequence.

example value = `5/ after 3 / 2 / 16 ...`

But my code is showning this values random like 16/5/3/2

This is my code

```
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Dim VarA As String, varFR, varLR

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblExample")        

    If rs.EOF Then
          FindRecordCount = 0
       Else
          rs.MoveLast
          FindRecordCount = rs.RecordCount
    End If        

    varLR = FindRecordCount
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    rs.MoveFirst
        varFR = 1
        Do While varFR < varLR
            If IsNull(rs.Fields(i).Value) = True Then
                GoTo pula1
            End If
                VarA = rs.Fields(i).Value
                Debug.Print VarA
pula1:
            rs.MoveNext
        varFR = varFR + 1
        Loop
    Next
```

Comment: Please use http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to provide sample data in its original format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables without primary key don't have an inbuilt sort order. So the result of a recordset loop can be random.

You can either provide the sort order when opening the recordset

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblExample ORDER BY Column1")
```

(but the result can still be random if Column1 contains duplicate values!)

or if you want the order, in which the records were inserted, add a `AutoNumber` **primary key** column to your table.

For readability you should still specify the order -

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblExample ORDER BY ID")
```

Comment: I don`t have needed to use your code, but the error was I don`t use the primary key so this is why access are given to me random values of my column. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you can loop trough like this, after you set the Recordset:

```
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
   ---  Stuff happens
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

So its looping through the records like they are in the table. If you want another sequence you can sort the recordset before:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblExample ORDER BY Column1 ASC")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and your time =D